# ffmpeg Command in exec()

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I Cant get this command working in exec()

```
ffmpeg -i ../uploads/".$row['videoid'].".".$row['van']." -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:rate=25,format=yuv420p[vid]" -map "[vid]" -map 0:a \
-codec:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset fast -codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 192k ../uploads/mp4sd/".$row['videoid'].".mp4
```

How do i place this in exec()?

This is not working:

```
exec(ffmpeg -i ../uploads/".$row['videoid'].".".$row['van']." -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:rate=25,format=yuv420p[vid]" -map "[vid]" -map 0:a \
-codec:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset fast -codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 192k ../uploads/mp4sd/".$row['videoid'].".mp4);
```

[image]

Comment: does this command working in command prompt?

Comment: did you check if exec is enabled

Comment: Can you paste the exact command you're using in the cli?

Comment: @Developer It's Enabled. Other commands are working fine but it has something to do with the :

Comment: can you echo/print whole command in web and run it in cli - sometime few parameters are not passed correctly. just check echo (ffmpet......)

Comment: @Developer i added a image of the code there you see what i mean

Comment: can you echo the command as mentioned below in answer and try to run command in cli

Comment: You are also missing the quotes exec ("yourcommand")

Comment: Could you please what this command does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There few way to find out problem.

1. First check if command and its parameters are correct by running it directly on command prompt.

If it is running fine on command prompt it should work cli

2. Secondly check if the  exec() command is installed and enabled.

   > ```
   > <?php
   > if(function_exists('exec')) {
   >     echo "exec is installed";
   > }
   > ?>
   > ```

> ```
> <?php
> function exec_enabled() {
>   $disabled = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
>   return !in_array('exec', $disabled);
> }
> ?>
> ```

3. if it is enabled and installed. thirdly you can echo the command in web and copy and past it cli to make sure all parameters are passed correctly in web.

> ```
> echo "ffmpeg -i ../uploads/".$row['videoid'].".".$row['van']." -filter_complex \
> "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:rate=25,format=yuv420p[vid]" -map "[vid]" -map 0:a \
> -codec:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset fast -codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 192k ../uploads/mp4sd/".$row['videoid'].".mp4";
> ```

also try this with quotes

```
exec("ffmpeg -i ../uploads/".$row['videoid'].".".$row['van']." -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:rate=25,format=yuv420p[vid]" -map "[vid]" -map 0:a \
-codec:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset fast -codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 192k ../uploads/mp4sd/".$row['videoid'].".mp4");
```